# OpenStreetMap and Country Borders in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I am new to QGIS and I am using OpenStreetMap and OSM place search to create a map for latin america. However the peruvian terrritory includes the maritime area. How can I avoid/modify this. All other countries are fine.

Answer (score 2):

The boundary out to sea includes the territorial waters.  To get one that matches the coast, a couple of quick solutions spring to mind. The first is to try using a different admin boundary level that avoids the sea.  If you are using admin level 2, try 4 instead or possibly 6.  You may need to dissolve states/provinces but looking at the [OSm data for Peru](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WikiProject_Peru), you can clearly see a boundary in the OSm data that matches the coast if you zoom in.

Alternatively, you can get a coastal boundary data set from [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-physical-vectors/) or [GSHHG](https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/gshhs.html) (available in a variety of resolutions - read the documentation).  You can the usse that to clip the OSM data.

Comment: there's also [openstreetmapdata](http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coast) which has higher resolution sea and land polygons.